# tensorflow_dataset image transform with dataset.map

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I am trying to load in the `cifar100 dataset` with the `tesorflow_dataset` library in Python. Once the data is loaded in with `.load()`, I am trying to transform the images to a set size with `.map()` the lambda inside of map gives me

> TypeError: () missing 2 required positional arguments:
>   'coarse_label' and 'label'

when running my code.

What is the best way to transform those images while keeping the label information in the data? I am not really sure how the lambda function interacts with the dataset.

This is done with tensorflow 2.0.0b1, tensorflow-datasets 1.0.2 and Python 3.7.3

```py
def transform_images(x_train, size):
    x_train = tf.image.resize(x_train, (size, size))
    x_train = x_train / 255
    return x_train

train_dataset = tfds.load(name="cifar100", split=tfds.Split.TRAIN)
train_dataset = train_dataset.map(lambda image, coarse_label, label: 
        (dataset.transform_images(image, FLAGS.size), coarse_label, label))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each row of your `train_dataset` is a dict, not a tuple. So you can't use `lambda` like `lambda image, coarse_label, label`.

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds

train_dataset = tfds.load(name="cifar100", split=tfds.Split.TRAIN)
print(train_dataset.output_shapes)

# {'image': TensorShape([32, 32, 3]), 'label': TensorShape([]), 'coarse_label': TensorShape([])}
```

You should use it like follows:

```py
def transform_images(row, size):
    x_train = tf.image.resize(row['image'], (size, size))
    x_train = x_train  / 255
    return x_train, row['coarse_label'], row['label']

train_dataset = train_dataset.map(lambda row:transform_images(row, 16))
print(train_dataset.output_shapes)

# (TensorShape([16, 16, 3]), TensorShape([]), TensorShape([]))
```

Comment: Works! You sir are a lifesaver. So why can I access the `row['image']` inside the function, but if I try to do `train_dataset['image']` I get:
`TypeError: '_OptionsDataset' object is not subscriptable` ?

Comment: @KennethWitham Each row of `train_dataset` is a dictionary, not that `train_dataset` is a dictionary.