# Resize tensorflow image from tensorflow_datasets

Tags: python, tensorflow, image-processing, tensorflow-datasets

I have modified the original `tfds` code of the CUB dataset [link](https://github.com/tensorflow/datasets/blob/master/tensorflow_datasets/image_classification/caltech_birds.py), as I am adding a text description to each of the images. My own version of the CUB dataset builds without problems, but my problem is when I try to resize the images.

I load my version of the CUB data set, called `mm_cub`, as follows:

```
mm_cub  = tfds.load("mm_cub")
data_dir = next(iter(mm_cub['train']))
```

Then, `data_dir` is a dictionary containing image, label, my_text, etc. I need to have access to these three variables, hence I cannot load my data with `mm_cub  = tfds.load("mm_cub",split='train',as_supervised=True)`, which downloads a tuple of images and labels.

I cannot create a dataset pipline with `map`, e.g.  `mm_cub = mm_cub.map(lambda image: tf.image.resize(image,[224,224])`, as `map` doesnt support dictionaries (at least I havent figured it out how to do it).

I have also tried to resize the images in the original `tfds` code, but as I understand the code, the images are decoded when they are loaded with `tfds.load` so I havent managed to figure it out how to resize the images in the original code.

Any suggestion about how to make a data pipeline that resizes the images while using `tfds`?

UPDATE: The answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56875027/tensorflow-dataset-image-transform-with-dataset-map) shows how to use `map` with a dictionary. I just modified `transform_images` as follows

```py
    def transform_images(row, size):
        x_train = tf.image.resize(row['image'], (size, size))
        x_train = x_train  / 255
        row['image'] = x_train
        
        return row
```

to keep the output as a dictionary